# Postgres performance degrading as cache gets consumed

Tags: postgresql, performance, caching, memory, centos

I migrated a Postgres database 9.1 doing 300K transactions/hour from a server with Red Hat OS, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz / 16 Core, 64 GB RAM, 240 GB x 4 Intel SSD TO Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz / 56 Core, 128 GB RAM, 2TB nvme PCI SSD, RANDOM READ 450000 iops, RANDOM WRITE 56000 iops. CentOS 6.9.

Over period of time the server slows down and the amount of data processed get reduced. If I clear the cache manually (sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches) then the data processing resume to maximum level. Again after some time with load the performance deteriorate in terms of amount of data processed. The cache memory shows it has been fully consumed.

pg configuration :

```
datestyle = 'redwood,show_time'
db_dialect = 'redwood'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
edb_dynatune = 90
edb_redwood_date = on
edb_redwood_strings = on
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/dbms_pipe,$libdir/edb_gen,$libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger,$libdir/plugins/plugin_spl_debugger'
timed_statistics = off
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p slave:/opt/PostgresPlus/9.1AS/wals/%f'
archive_mode = on
listen_addresses = '*'
log_destination = 'syslog'
syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
logging_collector = on
log_line_prefix = '%t'
max_wal_senders = 4
port = 6432
wal_keep_segments = 128
wal_level = hot_standby
temp_buffers='50MB'
constraint_exclusion = on
autovacuum = on
enable_bitmapscan = off
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 32GB
effective_cache_size = 96GB
work_mem = 167772kB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_segments = 64
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

Comment: Looks like you are overcommitting memory(check iostat or vmstat). Do you really need `max_connections = 200` ?` BTW: what is the setting for `random_page_cost` ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: random_age_cost is 4

Comment: Set it to 1.2. And lower `work_mem` and/or `max_connections` such that their product doesn't exceed  128GB/2

Comment: To fix this problem I have set the following setting to something around 5%-6% of your total physical RAM, divided by the number of cores in the server: In my case it was 128 GB RAM and 56 Core CPU.

sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=119837